# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Whenever I try to run this code in jupyter notebook:

```
#There is a class before this code 
def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi('chinesestock (1).ui', self)
        self.averagestockpricecalculate.clicked.connect(self.average)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.calcCoCo)
        stock = stocks()
        self.graphdatagraphdata.clicked.connect(self.graphdata)
        self.stocks = stock.stocks
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.grapha)
        # Line 47 is a line ahead, (the line that has the error)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.graphb)
```

I get this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-1-f169580a30e0>", line 50
bstock=self.averagestockstock1.currentText()
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

I already checked my spaces. I also tried pasting the code in another ipynb file but I get the same error on a different line.

Comment: You have one-too-many indentation in everything inside the `__init__` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied the code and pasted it into sublime text as a python file. Now it works, thanks!